# for or while loop to do something n times

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop, while-loop

In Python you have two fine ways to repeat some action more than once. One of them is `while` loop and the other - `for` loop. So let's have a look on two simple pieces of code:

```
for i in range(n):
    do_sth()
```

And the other:

```
i = 0
while i < n:
    do_sth()
    i += 1
```

My question is which of them is better. Of course, the first one, which is very common in documentation examples and various pieces of code you could find around the Internet, is much more elegant and shorter, but on the other hand it creates a completely useless list of integers just to loop over them. Isn't it a waste of memory, especially as far as big numbers of iterations are concerned?

So what do you think, which way is better?

Comment: @CiroSantilliПутлерКапут六四事 That is definitely not a duplicate.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> but on the other hand it creates a completely useless list of integers just to loop over them. Isn't it a waste of memory, especially as far as big numbers of iterations are concerned?

That is what `xrange(n)` is for. It avoids creating a list of numbers, and instead just provides an iterator object.

In Python 3, `xrange()` was renamed to `range()` - if you want a list, you have to specifically request it via `list(range(n))`.

Comment: I'd like to note that while less memory-efficient (without `xrange`), the for loop is much faster, there's no extra comparison and addition.

Comment: Good to know all that! Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 22):

This is lighter weight than `xrange` (and the while loop) since it doesn't even need to create the `int` objects. It also works equally well in Python2 and Python3

```
from itertools import repeat
for i in repeat(None, 10):
    do_sth()
```

Comment: It requires importing itertools on the other hand, which is a bit inconvenient. Amber's answer looks better.

Comment: It's inconvenient for code golf. Not sure why people think import is some sort of problem. Besides real programs have a bunch of imports and itertools has lots of stuff you should be using anyway.

Comment: Well, I assume that when you could do something with the core language  equally good as with a module, then why import? Itertools is extremely useful for certain purposes, true, but I can imagine a lot of Python scripts working nicely without it. That's why it's a module and not core Python. :)

Comment: `for i in xrange(n):` is also more idiomatic, which is honestly far more important than an `import` either way.

Comment: You can also repeat the method you are intending to call: `[fn() for fn in repeat(self.callable_thing, 10)]` ... should save a lookup on each iteration.

Comment: @F1Rumors, Using a list comprehension purely for side effects is generally discouraged.

Comment: Fair point @JohnLaRooy, I was capturing the results, which is not part of the original question.  In that form, `for fn in repeat(self.callable_thing, 10): fn()` is the right thing to do...

Answer (score 11):

## python3 & python2

just use `range()`:

```py
for _ in range(n):
    # do something n times exactly
```

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental difference in most programming languages is that *unless* the unexpected happens a `for` loop will **always** repeat `n` times *or until a break statement, (which may be conditional), is met* then finish with a `while` loop it may repeat `0 times, 1, more or even forever`, depending on a given condition which must be true at the start of each loop for it to execute and always false on exiting the loop, (for completeness a `do ... while` loop, (or `repeat until`), for languages that have it, always executes at least once and does not guarantee the condition on the first execution).

It is worth noting that in Python a `for` or `while` statement can have `break`, `continue` and `else` [statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) where:

- `break` - terminates the loop
- `continue` - moves on to the next time around the loop without executing following code this time around
- `else` - is executed if the loop completed without any `break` statements  being executed.

**N.B.** In *the now unsupported* Python 2 `range` produced a list of integers but you could use `xrange` to use an iterator. In Python 3 `range` returns an iterator.

So the answer to your question is '*it all depends on what you are trying to do*'!

Comment: It is absolutely not true that a `for` loop will **always** repeat `n` times. It is very common to have `break` statements inside `for` loops to make them repeat less than `n` times.

Comment: @AndrésMejía - my original answer did state "unless the unexpected" - my edit should clarify with details on break, continue and else.