# How to repeat a while loop a certain number of times

Tags: python, python-3.x

As seen [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647907/for-or-while-loop-to-do-something-n-times), there are two ways to repeat something a number of times. But it does not seem to work for me, so I was wondering if anybody could help.

Basically, I want to repeat the following 3 times

```
 import random
 a = []
 w = 0

 while w<4:
     x = random.uniform(1,10)
     print(x)
     print(w)
     a.append(w+x)
     print(a)
     w=w+1
```

Based on what the link says, this is what I did,

```
 import random
 a = []
 w = 0
 r = 0


 while r < 3: 
      while w<4:
          x = random.uniform(1,10)
          print(x)
          print(w)
          a.append(w+x)
          print(a)
          w = w+1
      r += 1
```

But this doesn't seem to work. The while loop only repeats once instead of three times. Could anybody help me fix this problem?

Comment: Put w=0 inside outer loop

Comment: Or even better use:  for r in range(3): for w in range(4):

Comment: [A tutorial](https://www.w3schools.in/python-tutorial/loops/) might help you understand the logic of Python loops. You can visualise the execution of your Python program [on Pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit). This allows you to observe intermediate variables and execute your program step by step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by @R2RT, you need to reset `w` after each `r` loop. Try writing this:

```
import random
 a = []
 w = 0
 r = 0


 while r < 3: 
      while w<4:
          x = random.uniform(1,10)
          print(x)
          print(w)
          a.append(w+x)
          print(a)
          w = w+1
      r += 1
      w = 0
```

Answer (score 10):

To repeat something for a certain number of times, you may:

1. Use `range` or `xrange`

   ```
   for i in range(n):
       # do something here
   ```
2. Use `while`

   ```
   i = 0
   while i < n:
       # do something here
       i += 1
   ```
3. If the loop variable `i` is irrelevant, you may use `_` instead

   ```
   for _ in range(n):
       # do something here

   _ = 0
   while _ < n
       # do something here
       _ += 1
   ```

As for nested `while` loops, remember to always keep the structure:

```
i = 0
while i < n:

    j = 0
    while j < m:
        # do something in while loop for j
        j += 1

    # do something in while loop for i
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I dont see the

> w=w+1

in your code, why you removed that?
Add `w=w+1` before `r=r+1`.

Good luck.

Comment: I actually did write w = w+1 in the actual code. I just forgot to write it here. Thanks for letting me know. :) I will edit.

Comment: @Max You must reset w to 0 after leaving internal `while`