# While loop based on USER INPUT

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

How can I make a while loop print something blank amount of times based on the user input. For example:

```
age = int(input('Enter your age: '))

while age…
```

And I just don’t know what to do from there. To be clear, how could I output something 8 times if the user inputs 8 (6 times if the user inputs six…)?

Edit:
I want to run a while loop based on the USER INPUT, if they enter 3, it will print something 3 times. I don’t know what they will enter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [for or while loop to do something n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647907/for-or-while-loop-to-do-something-n-times)

Comment: If you want to do something x number of times, use `for _ in range(x)`.

Comment: So I can't comment unless it's a fully fleshed, bulletproof, Congress-approved answer?  Good luck with that attitude.

Comment: I am fully aware that my comment was not a full answer.  That's why I posted it as a _comment_, not an _answer_.

Answer (score 1):

With a `while`-loop you have to use a condition for how long it will execute.
To keep the value assigned to `age` use a counter variable like so:

```py
age = int(input("Enter your age: "))

n = 0
while n < age:
    # Do something n-times as restricted by age
    n += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is:

```py
x = input(“What’s your age?”)

for x in range(x):

     #do something (x) times
```

This will ensure that the amount of times the program will do something `x` will be up to user input. Hope this helps!

Comment: be sure type(x) : int